# Offset-Bootstrap4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

No logro que funcione la propiedad Offset. En el ejemplo ejecutable no podréis apreciarlo bien ya que esta muy encogido y puse esa propiedad para large(lg).
Podéis verlo mejor acá:  http://equipostaff.hol.es/BT4.html

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
        <h1>Casilla 1</h1>
        <p>Contenido casilla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4" style="background-color:#ddd">
        <h1>Casilla 2</h1>
        <p>Contenido casilla</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4  offset-lg-4" style="background-color:#ccc">
        <h1>Casilla 3</h1>
        <p>Contenido casilla</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:#aaa">
        <h1>Casilla 4</h1>
        <p>Contenido casilla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4  offset-lg-4" style="background-color:#ddd">
        <h1>Casilla 5</h1>
        <p>Contenido casilla</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas Vendetta: 1) el ejecutable tiene un boton de pantalla completa asi se soluciona el "muy encogido". 2)dices que no logras que funcione. Puedes explicar con más detalle el resultado esperado? No estás usando la propiedad `offset` directamente, si no una clase. Un saludo

Comment: Estás usando una versión de bootstrap que hace poco ha pasado a beta y están cambiando cosas. Ya no existe la clase `offset`, tienes esto en su lugar http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns pero no tiene el mismo funcionamiento. Tendrás que mirar bien la documentación y usar la última versión o cambiar a la versión 3 que lleva tiempo y es estable.